# What is the motivation behind defining Deterministic Looping Automata?

Tags: fl.formal-languages, automata-theory

I was wondering about what could possibly be the motivation behind defining the deterministic looping automata? What puzzles me is that they accept a word iff they have a run on it!

I believe they are strongly related to DBWs. And i would like to see how.

My intuition:
since we can assume W.l.o.g that each non-accepting state $q$ in a DBW $A$ has a loop of non-accepting states containing q. Maybe one can look at the $strongly$ $connected$ $components$ of $A_{rej}$, Where $A_{rej}$ denotes $A$ restricted to non-accepting states, as looping automata.

Relevant papers could help.

Note: i am new to research. In particular i have few knowledge about DBWs. Its more a reference than a question.

thanks.

Comment: What's a DBW?  Which definition of looping automata are you using?

Comment: DBW $A=(\Sigma, Q, q_0, \delta, F)$ is deteriministic büchi automaton where $\delta$ is a partial function from $Q \times \Sigma$ to $Q$. And a deterministic looping automaton $A$ is defined exactly as the deterministic büchi automaton **but**  all states are accepting. i.e., $F=Q$.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In a looping automaton, the transition function is not assumed to be *total*. That is, for a state $q$ and a letter $\sigma$, it could be the case that $\delta(q,\sigma)$ is undefined.
Intuitively, this is the same as having a transition to a rejecting sink.

So they are "deterministic" in the sense that there is no non-determinism. But still, this means that for every word either there is a single run, or there are no runs. Thus, saying that a word is accepted iff it has a run on it is not a trivial acceptance condition.

The reason for studying these automata is that they correspond to *safety properties*. A safety property is a language $L$ such that for every word $w\notin L$, there exists some prefix $x$ of $w$ such that for every suffix $y$, $x\cdot y\notin L$. That is, once you read $x$, there is no way to get in the language. 
These properties are useful in practice, as they correspond to "system failure", in a way. That is, once something really bad happens, you can't recover.

Technically, these autoamta are useful because of their simple acceptance condition.

As for references, start [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safety_property). Also, [Orna Kupferman](http://www.cs.huji.ac.il/~ornak/pub.html) has several papers using these objects (but I suspect you already know that... :) )

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer. And your suspicion seems to be correct :)